# rosbag play on two machines

Tags: ros, rosbag, machines, multiple, synchronization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have recorded simultaneously multiple cameras sequences on two machines with rosbag.
I now would like to replay this sequence simulataneously on the two machines (to avoid transfer images on the network) with a good synchronization.
Is it possible to do it with rosbag or should I need to code this myself ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50060/rosbag-play-on-two-machines/) by [Amaury Negre](https://answers.ros.org/users/3753/amaury-negre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2012-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think that is possible with rosbag. You will have to implement it yourself.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0